# How do you check that promise is resolved in jasmine >2.3?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a bunch of tests that check if a promise is resolved or rejected. In Jasmine 2.0 I could do the following:

```
it('should resolve promise', done => {
    viewModel.canDeactivate().then(() => {
        done();
    });
});
```

In this example `viewModel.canDeactivate()` returns the promise and I am trying to check its state. So, I am not using expectations but just call `done` callback in `then` to mark that test passed. If something is wrong I get a timeout exception and that is kind of OK to mark test as failed.

But the latest version of Jasmine does not like such tests, I am getting a lot of errors in console and they are marked as SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS in the output.

How do you deal with such cases and how do you check a state of the promise?
Thanks in advance!

- I am using native promises. I know that in libraries such as Q we can inspect the state of the promise, but I do not now the same thing for the native promises.

Comment: SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS indicates that Jasmine just wants something to be asserted. You have a test that does not assert anything (it just has to "survive" in order to pass).

Perhaps add something simple like `expect(1).toBe(1)` to make Jasmine run the test? (Perhaps you can also do a more sane expectation).

Comment: Yes, I think that expect(1).toBe(1) will solve that. But the  question is actually about how to write a sane expectation

Comment: Perhaps the canDeactivate method produces some effects you can assert on?

Comment: It returns undefined and calls some other stuff. I do assert that calls, but  also want to check that promise is resolved

Comment: You're already checking that the promise gets resolved. The first callback of then() is only called when the promise gets resolved (the second callback or next catch() if rejected).